# How can the alpha channel be -1?

Tags: java, alpha

I am wondering how the alpha channel of a single pixel can be -1? I am going through each pixel of a PNG image (loaded in a buffered image, ARGB type). Many of the alpha values are -1 (the others are larger than zero) - how is that possible? Shouldn't the value be between 0 and 255? Code follows below. Thanks for any hint!

```
// imagine some great loop for x and y before this code
int a = (scaledImage.getRGB(x, y) & 0xff000000) >> 24; // kill all bits except for the first 8, shift 24 to the right to get them
System.out.println("" + a);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into a sign extension problem. Use the unsigned shift operator `>>>` instead.

Comment: Thank you for also delivering the solution to the problem!

Answer (score 0):

If you treat it as unsigned int, -1 = 0xFF = 255. It's just another way of interpreting a 255 value for the alpha channel.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, Adam! Unfortunately I can't see if you or erickson was faster, will accept ericksons answer as it also provides a solution to this problem, but yours is also very helpful!